# Javascript - Ajax call from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to call a Ajax javascript function from the codebehind which fetches the data. I am using below method to do the same :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(), 
    "MyKey", 
    "Myfunction();", 
    true);
```

If I put an alert in place of MyFunction() here, it works but when I put my function then it is not working :

```
   CsText.Append("var Announcements; ")

   CsText.Append("}}} ")
   CsText.Append(" $('.ui-checkbox').checkbox();")
```

If I run above query from javascript, it works fine. Any suggestion??
Is it that we cannot call an ajax method from code-behind? or it is using js file in this call so it is not able to find the reference or is there any other way to do this, like can I put all this inside a function in front-end code & call that method itself from back-end using RegisterStartupScript. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyKey", "Myfunction();", true);
```

OR

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyKey", "Myfunction();", true);
```

OR

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyKey", "<script>Myfunction();</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call would work if your code correctly render on client side. but what you have written is not a correct way. I would rather write js code seperate and calling it using RegisterStartupScript method.

**Js Code**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function Myfunction(){
       $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "SharepointListsAccess.asmx", cache: false
        });
   }
  </script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
GetType(), 
"MyKey", 
"Myfunction();", 
true);
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it out.

Comment: If I use this as a method then on execution the script of the method is displayed on the screen. like function Myfunction() { alert(1); }
This is getting displayed on screen.

Comment: Any thought, why is it displaying script?

Comment: I think there is some confliction. try this code in brand new page.